# A newcomer's riddle - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

With me, I help form a triad.

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

**What am I?**

EDIT: Omitted an incorrect word from the last line.

**Hint:**

> You will know my number from 1 to 7 with light and some water.

Comment: >! Minor flaw... Your first two lines mix up primary colors with pixels. Yellow red and blue are primary colors, not green!

Comment: I mentioned that they form a triad. Nothing about primary colours. However, I have added an edit to the accepted answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are

> The color green

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Red & Blue are representative of angry & sad, respectively. Green is the third of the primary (OP: additive) colors, so w/o it you're only angry & sad, leading to the next clue:

With me, I help form a triad.

> Red / Green / Blue are the primary colors. 
>  OP: Green helps form the primary additive colours

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> ROYGBIV (1-7), not Red or Violet

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Green is present pretty much everywhere? Except urban areas, most parts of the ocean, arctic tundras, and most parts of the desert... but most areas where people are, at least. OP: Deuteranomaly is a reduced sensitivity to green light (colourblindness)

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Green light = go

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Green checkmark = correct answer

Comment: @Jace has the same answer as you with different explanations, and his is two minutes earlier. Not sure what the asker will accept but just letting you know.

Comment: Actually, Red/Green/Blue are *not* the primary colors - it's Yellow, not Green.

Comment: @Mithrandir he probably thought of RGB and got confused

Comment: @AditKirtani Woops, yeah, I was thinking rgb for color values.

Comment: @mdc32 k, thanks. He probably submitted while I was typing haha

Comment: Red, Green and Blue are the primary colors of light; cyan, magenta and yellow, the colors of pigment. Red, Yellow and Blue as primary colors is a falsehood from the old days of classical painters, still promoted (nobody really knows why) by primary school teachers, who will, after making a color wheel with the wrong colors, and seeing it makes brown, say "well, that's because they give us cheap paints!"

Comment: In additive color models, red, green, and blue are primary colors. The classic red, yellow, blue is a subtractive color model

Comment: @Axle No, the subtractive color model is [Cyan, Magenta, and Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)

Comment: @DewiMorgan -- I actually spoke to a painter about this. I said theoretically you should be able to get red from mixing magenta and yellow paints. She said it doesn't work out that way (you get something muddy). It's because in painting the pigments aren't spectrally pure. So they pick a different set of colors (red, yellow, blue) as a basis for making more. (There are also a ton of other pigments made from different substances.)

Comment: @mbomb007 Both CMY and RYB are considered [subtractive color models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_color). CMY is used a lot in printing, while RYB is used in painting, but both are subtractive models.

Comment: @MackTuesday - Color print cartridges come in CMY, the "primary colors of pigment" and modern prints aren't muddy: your painter friend is just parroting their art teacher, a century outdated. Put differently: RG&B are the spectral frequencies at which the three different cone cells in the typical trichromatic human eye have their peak sensitivities. C and Y are the colors between B&G and G&R, while M isn't a "real color", but rather a mix of two outer frequencies which together trigger the B and R cells without triggering G in the middle. Using just RYB, you just can't mix a magenta.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the correct answer because it has only one reasoning that is not what it is intended to be. The only reasoning that is off here is the 'In very few cases I won't be seen.' line which is meant to reflect a form of green colourblindness as stated in the other answer so I would appreciate that if you edited that into your answer. Otherwise, well done.

Comment: _mixing magenta and yellow paints._ this is exactly what every color printer does and quite successfully - but not by mixing the colors directly but by mixing dots of pure color on the canvas. Your painter is right and wrong; you may want to talk to him/her about pointilism!

Comment: @DewiMorgan -- Yeah I wasn't disagreeing with anything you said. I was talking about the limitations of paint. Printers use particular inks that are fairly spectrally pure, which is what makes CMYK work. On the other hand most paints don't have such purity, and it's often easier to get a good red by just using a single pigment paint. Again, I'm not saying the CMYK model is wrong, I'm saying imperfect pigments confuse the issue for painters, especially considering they're able to get their work done using the imperfect RYB model.

Comment: Regarding being between 1 and 7, we could also point out that green=2 (i.e., 32 and 42) in the [ANSI color codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), and that it is always the second component [when a color is represented as a triad of primary components](http://www.color-hex.com/color/00ff00).

Answer (score 28):

I think it is

> Green

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Without green (money), you would be angry and sad

With me, I help form a triad.

> Green is part of the RGB primary color triad for additive colors

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> Seven colors in the rainbow, not 1 (red) and not 7 (violet), but in between.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> The most common type of color blindness is Red-green, so some people cannot see green.

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Proceed at a green light

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Green (money) for selling a house? (by transferring a deed) I'm not 100% on this one yet.

Comment: "You'll see me when you've done the deed." = upvotes?

Comment: @NobodyNada Good point, the check does seem more likely.

Comment: accepted answers have a green check

Comment: This is correct, but the reasonings for the first line and last line are slightly off what was intended. The other answer was off by only one reasoning so I accepted that one. Regardless, you did a good job matching all the other reasonings.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT new awsner :

You are

> Money

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Wihtout money, we are sad or angry (losing money)

With me, I help form a triad.

> A triad is one of many branches of Chinese organized crime, which can smuggle, counterfeite and launder money.

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> 3 and 4 on keyboard can make money symboles, £ and $ in my case.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Some people will never see money (the really poor)

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Still looking, maybe referre to 'Time is money', using time to proceed (solve) the riddle

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> In real estate, a deed involve money and loan

Comment: Interesting deductions but its not the answer either. Each line holds its own clue, including the last two lines that you placed together.

Comment: I think if you want to have a different guess you should post another answer, so that people can see the answer you already guessed beforehand, which for the benefit of people who didnt see it - it was 'happy'. In regards to your new answer 'money'. Its not the answer...however, wherever there is money, you could say the answer is there too.

Comment: @hypern I thought of adding a new awnser, but when I tryed It recommended editing or commenting, but I take note of it. Alright, I got to try harder then.

Answer (score 9):

You are:

> The diphthong "ee"

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Lack of glee

With me, I help form a triad.

> The word three

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> ee is in "between"

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Seen

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Proceed

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Deed

Answer (score 6):

You are

> Red

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Your face get red when angry or after crying for a while

With me, I help form a triad.

> RGB color

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> 7 colors in the rainbow

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Infrared

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> You stop at a red light, when it changes to green, you can proceed on your way

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Blood will be spilt when the deed is done (killed someone)

Answer (score 5):

You are

> 2

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

With me, I help form a triad.

> A triad is a group of three, so you need 1, 2, and 3

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere inbetween

> 2 is between 1 and 7

In very few cases I wont be seen.

> The word representation has multiple homophones--namely to, two, and too--which are all very commonly used words

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

You'll see me <s>again</s> when you've done the deed

Comment: Still working on a few; I'll gladly take some help

Comment: Good ideas but its not the answer

Comment: Is the answer a number?

Comment: It's not a number

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Child

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Not being with your child can make you angry and sad

With me, I help form a triad.

> If it's your only child that makes three of you in the family.

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> Tween can mean young child and it's 'in between'

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Not too sure on this.  Maybe they're staying with the grandparents?? :)

To solve this riddle, now proceed...
You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> You've got to do the deed before you make a child.

Comment: I think your answer is creative, but its not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You are

> blue

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> feeling blue?

With me, I help form a triad.

> RGB is colour

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> 7 colours in the rainbow

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> ultravioliet?

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> don't know

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> If you do the deed - kill someone - the police (blue) will come

Comment: You are so very close. You have the right idea with the triad and the numbers 1-7.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is

> Yellow

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Without yellow you are left with red (angry) and blue (sad)

With me, I help form a triad.

> Three primary colours

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> Colours of the rainbow are 7 yellow is between the first and last. Red and Violet would usually be considered number 1 and 7.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Colour blindness (Tritanopia) could result in not seeing yellow)

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Not sure, possibly something to do with yellow traffic lights which can sort of mean proceed.

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Not sure

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> Carbon

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Most our food is carbon based, and lack of food can make people sad or angry.

With me, I help form a triad.

> Its chemical compound contains carbon, (ie CO2)

or as Christopher suggest in comment

> Carbon with Nitrogen and Oxygen forms a Döbereiner's triad

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> Carbon atomic number is 6, and six is between 1 and 7

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Some compounds containing carbon are invisible for human eye (ie CO2)

Comment: It also forms a Döbereiner's triad with Nitrogen and Oxygen.

Comment: @ChristopherD. That might me it, i edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Power

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Without power (electric or physical) we are sad or angry

With me, I help form a triad.

> Power (electricity) form The Triad charging system (in UK)

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> 6 can make ^ which is representation of mathematic power operation

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Some doesn't have power at all OR hide their true potential

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> With power?

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> If I do the riddle, I will gain reputation/power !

Comment: Its not correct, but I added a hint to the riddle which may help solve it.

Answer (score 1):

As a newcomer, let me try.

I think it is:

> Greed

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> Once you lost this emotion on your decision, planning or expect, you might feel angry or/and sad.

With me, I help form a triad.

> For the Honor and power, Greed can let you raise from a triad, which triad means the branch of Chinese organized crime.

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> On the concept of Seven deadly sins, Greed is the 3rd.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Tons of criminal cases because of greed.

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Greed "encourage" us to find the correct answer.

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> You feels good once helping the others, it "encourage" doing more and more, affected by a little bit of Greed. (Too hard to explain :P)

You will know my number from 1 to 7 with light and some water.

> You can see your own face since most of us has "Greed" as a Human being.

Just try to answer, please forgive my horrible grammar as an Asian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you maybe a

> chord?

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> i.e. without music.

With me, I help form a triad.

> triad, in the musical sense.

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> chords typically consist of between 2 and 7 notes.

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> Got nothing...

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> Still nothing...

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> Yep, still nothing...

Comment: Its a very intelligent answer but its not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems, that by merely suggesting you don't have or are continuing to work on some of the answers, you'll get downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

The answer

> the letter "I".
> Couldn't find anything good for relation with angry

Without me, you'd be angry and sad.

> remove I from said becomes  sad

With me, I help form a triad.

> I in triad

I'm not 1, not 7 but somewhere in between.

> I is not in one or seven. But in between - five and six

In very few cases I won't be seen.

> It clearly shouts "I" wont be seen. and also no I in few or cases

To solve this riddle, now proceed...

> just proceed

You'll see me when you've done the deed.

> when you solve that its "I". You complete the deed and you see it again in "what am I". You once again see "I"